# CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER with curl_multi

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the curl_multi functions with PHP. I already know that you can return the request contents from `curl_exec` when the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` flag is on. However, how can we grab the request contents of multiple requests as strings when using `curl_multi_exec`?

<del>Does it return an array when this flag is set?</del> Nope, `curl_multi_exec` can only return `true` or `false`, without the option to return the contents like the normal one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, the `curl_multi_getcontent` function, while somewhat inelegant, works for getting the contents as strings from each individual curl handle.